# Change dropdown menu when time is changed

Tags: javascript, php, drop-down-menu

i write a php site/javascript function  for changing a dropdown menu when time is between e.g. 7.00-8.00(id530) or 13-15(id1330) or 20-03(id2130). If time is 7.31 the dropdown menu should display/change onload of the site to id530.

i've tried to compare the time with strtotime but im not sure how to get
this in the javascript funtion.

```
<select id="soa" name="soa" required style="width: 154px" 
onload="var  selectBoxField = document.getElementById('soa')
var fieldNumber = document.getElementById('$time')
fieldNumber.addEventListener('keyup', ({target}) => {  
var index = Array.from(selectBoxField).findIndex(option => option.id === target.value);
selectBoxField.selectedIndex = index;
})">
            <option id="530" value="1">s1</option>
            <option id="1330" value="2">s2</option>
            <option id="2130" value="3">s3/option>
            </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting your code into the element's onload function, try triggering it separately, when the whole window has surely loaded, including your $time element:

```
<script>
        window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
            var  selectBoxField = document.getElementById('soa');
            var fieldNumber = document.getElementById('$time');
            fieldNumber.addEventListener('keyup', ({target}) => {  
                var index = Array.from(selectBoxField).findIndex(option => option.id === target.value);
                selectBoxField.selectedIndex = index;
            });
        });
</script>
```

If your problem still stands, please edit your post so it contains the $time element too, so I can test it fully.

**EDIT:** Also mind the fact that your third option doesn't have a proper closing tag: `/option>`